# Como chamar o construtor dentro de um método

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos, construtor

Tenho um exercício simples de faculdade pra mexer com o vetor. Basicamente são essas ações que devemos fazer:

```cpp
    cout << "\tMexendo com Vetor\n";
    cout << "\n\nEscolha uma das opcoes para fazer com o Vetor:";
    cout << "\n01 - Imprimir ";
    cout << "\n02 - Adicionar";
    cout << "\n03 - Limpar ";
    cout << "\n04 - Localizar um numero";
    cout << "\n05 - Excluir o numero de uma posicao";
    cout << "\n06 - Trocar o numero de posicao";
    cout << "\n\n00 - Encerrar o programa";
```

Na opção "03 - Limpar" tem que limpar o vetor inteiro.

Pra isso eu gostaria de chamar o Construtor dentro do meu método, afinal ele inicia o meu objeto com o vetor limpo, fazendo o mesmo que a opção escolhida!

Meu método Limpar:

```cpp
void Vetor::clear_vet () {
    while (contador != 0) { del_pos(0); }
}
```

Atualmente ele fica chamando outro método (o de deletar a posição) e fica deletando a primeira posição até não ter mais nenhum elemento (quando o contador chegar a 0)

A ideia que eu tive seria tipo isso:

```cpp
void Vetor::clear_vet () {
    Vetor();
}
```

meu arquivo `.hpp` pra caso tenham alguma dúvida:

```
#ifndef VETOR_HPP
#define VETOR_HPP

#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

using namespace std;


class Vetor {    
    private:
        int contador, i;
        int vet[10];
    public:
        Vetor () { 
            contador = 0; 

            for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) { vet[i] = 0; } 
            };
        void print ();
        void add_vet (float num);
        bool del_pos (int pos1);
        void clear_vet ();
        int loc_num (float num);
        bool change_pos (int pos1, int pos2);
        bool valid(int pos);
};      

#endif // VETOR_HPP
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao que parece é isso que deseja:

```
void Vetor::clear_vet() {
    contador = 0; 
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) vet[i] = 0;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Algorithm/CleanVector.cpp).

Eventualmente, apenas para tornar o código mais fácil de dar manutenção, como algo mais avançado, mas não precisa fazer se não entende porque está fazendo isso, talvez queira ter um método privado para colocar esse código e chamar dentro do método acima e do construtor esse novo método que serve justamente [para evitar repetição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101), assim a informação de como fazer a inicialização fica canônica. Se achar complicado entender, não faça, use o jeito que eu fiz acima.

Chamar o construtor criaria outro objeto novo e não é isso que deseja, não faça isso.

Dependendo da situação não é de todo ruim fazer o que já fazia, talvez nem tenha perda de eficiência alguma se o compilador achar que deve otimizar, e se ele não otimizar provavelmente é porque não precisa. Mas só se o método for muito bem feito e seja pensado para limpar o último elemento sem custo adicional, mas como eu tenho quase certeza que não está pensado para isso então é melhor não usar, mas fica a dica que o método não parece ser bom.

Não faça uma variável que só é usada localmente parte integrante do objeto.

Tem indícios de haver outros problemas aí, mas sem ver o todo nem daria para garantir. Inclusive pode ajudar aprender alguns mecanismos, mas provavelmente está desensinando como se criar uma estrutura de dados corretamente, tenha isso em mente para não fixar isso como se fosse correto, porque funcionar é diferente de star certo.

Comment: Não entendi, chamar outro método dentro de um método eh errado? A parte de que não se deve chamar o Construtor novamente eu entendi. No caso da variável local, eu não vejo outra forma pra verificar quantos elementos já foram colocados, além de que essa variável tb eh usada em outros métodos para fazer as outras operações..

Comment: Não, eu não disse isso. Você não precisa de `i` para saber quantos elementos já foram usados.

Comment: Qual seria uma outra maneira pra isso?

Comment: Do jeito que eu fiz.

Comment: Entendi, obr !!